# What is an axis aligned integer bounding box?

Tags: mathematics, bounding-boxes, computational-geometry

In [this](http://cg.cs.uni-bonn.de/project-pages/hairmodeling/documents/RapidCollisonDetection.pdf) paper, in the **Distance field computation** section, it says that an axis aligned integer bounding box of a Prism has to be calculated. Can someone explain what an axis aligned integer bounding box is and how can it be calculated for a Prism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An axis-aligned bounding box is a simplified representation of some object's volume and position. In this case, I think an axis aligned *integer* bounding box would be a bounding box that can only have integral dimensions, and an integral position.

If this definition is accurate, then a bounding box like this could be found if you found the highest vertex, representing the position of the top of the box, the lowest vertex in the prism representing the bottom of the box, most left vertex representing the left side of the box, and so on. Once you had all coordinates you'd need to make them integers, so you'd "round away" from the centre of the prism, like how you can round away from zero. This is so the box's sides don't intersect with the prism, and the prism is contained within the box.